# mysql is not starting on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

When i boot my machine, mysql doesn't start.

```
service mysql start
```

gives

```
start: Job failed to start
```

dmesg has the following strange entries. Any clue what might be happening. I am using dual core machine with 2 GB RAM and Ubuntu 14.04

```
sbin/mysqld" pid=2009 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   86.920938] init: mysql main process (2021) terminated with status 1
[   86.920956] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[   87.346587] init: mysql post-start process (2022) terminated with status 1
[   87.355855] type=1400 audit(1441601497.326:74): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=2065 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=2069 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   88.973965] init: mysql main process (2081) terminated with status 1
[   88.973995] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

I tried the following:
 1. Changed bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to IP address. Didn't work
 2. Increased innodb_buffer_pool_size to 128M. Didn't work
 3. Socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock exists and has requisite permissions.
 4. apt-get upgrade, apt-get distro-upgrade, apt-get update and tried to reinstall mysql-server

Comment: Is the ``mysqld`` daemon running?

Comment: show your mysql config file

Comment: `ps -aef | grep mysqld`
`root      2658  1925  0 01:34 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysqld`

Comment: any specific entries from mysql config? here are the most common ones

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M`

Answer (score 0):

The best clue to find out is to check the logs :

less /var/log/mysql.err or /var/log/mysql.log

If you don’t find it there check this file to find where are your mysql logs being written :  /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf

Usually it is in your syslog.

Open another terminal and type this :

tail -f /var/log/syslog

then

type : service mysql restart

you will see the errors in the syslog and you can find out the solution.

Comment: I tried this and got same error as mentioned earlier. Mainly 
`type=1400 audit(1441605104.658:86): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=3071 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=3075 comm="apparmor_parser"
start: Job failed to start`

`mysql main process (2967) terminated with status 1` and `mysql respawning too fast, stopped`

Comment: Try to change this in your my.cnf :

default-character-set = utf8
default-collation     = utf8_general_ci

with:

character_set_server  = utf8
collation_server      = utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't any clue in default mysql error log file, try to start mysqld from raw in verbose mode to see all messages in the console output:

```
su mysql
mysqld -v
```

The output messages can be helpful to find out the root cause that prevents mysql to start.